# CSS rules merging

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-sass

I am working to implement RTL support on a large framework. For that, I replaced all of the rules that are directional with mixins like:

```
a {
  @include padding(0, 1px, 0, 0);
  @include margin(0, 1px, 0, 0);
}
```

What this does, is to add the relevant padding/margin depending on the direction of the document.

Every mixin creates a case for `ltr` and a case for `rtl`.

This is the result from those mixins:

```
[dir="ltr"] a {
  padding: 0 1px 0 0;
}
[dir="rtl"] a {
  padding: 0 0 0 1px;
}
[dir="ltr"] a {
  margin: 0 1px 0 0;
}
[dir="rtl"] a {
  margin: 0 0 0 1px;
}
```

Which works, and is fine, but creates a lot of duplicate selectors (2 per mixin), so the css bundle size increases by 100kb (20%), and a large part of it is because of this duplication.

Expected result:

```
[dir="ltr"] a {
  padding: 0 1px 0 0;
  margin: 0 1px 0 0;
}
[dir="rtl"] a {
  padding: 0 0 0 1px;
  margin: 0 0 0 1px;

}
```

What post-processing I can do to merge relevant duplicate selectors, without hurting the order of css execution?

**Undesired case:**

Lets say I have this code:

```
b.s1 { 
  padding-left: 1px; 
  margin: 0; 
}

b.s2 { 
  padding-left: 0; 
  margin: 1px; 
}

b.s1 { 
  padding-left: 1px; 
}
```

If I merge b.s1 upwards, then s2's padding-left can override it. 
If I merge b.s1 downwards, then s2's margin is overriden.

Is there any solution to this problem?

EDIT: Original code

```
// Add property for all sides
// @param {string} $prop
// @param {string} $top
// @param {string} $end
// @param {string} $bottom
// @param {string} $start
// @param {boolean} $content include content or use default
// ----------------------------------------------------------
@mixin property($prop, $top, $end: $top, $bottom: $top, $start: $end, $content: false) {
  @if $top == $end and $top == $bottom and $top == $start {
    @include multi-dir() {
      #{$prop}: $top;
    }
  } @else if $top == $bottom and $end == $start and $top != null and $end != null {
    @include multi-dir() {
      #{$prop}: $top $end;
    }
  } @else if $end == $start and $top != null and $end != null and $bottom != null {
    @include multi-dir() {
      #{$prop}: $top $end $bottom;
    }
  } @else if $top != null and $end != null and $bottom != null and $start != null {
    @include ltr() {
      #{$prop}: $top $end $bottom $start;
    }
    @include rtl() {
      #{$prop}: $top $start $bottom $end;
    }
  } @else {
    @if $content == true { // TODO check if @content exists instead
      @content;
    } @else {
      @include property-horizontal($prop, $start, $end);
      @include multi-dir() {
        #{$prop}-top: $top;
        #{$prop}-bottom: $bottom;
      }
    }
  }
}
// Add padding for all sides
// @param {string} $top
// @param {string} $end
// @param {string} $bottom
// @param {string} $start
// ----------------------------------------------------------
@mixin padding($top, $end: $top, $bottom: $top, $start: $end) {
  @include property(padding, $top, $end, $bottom, $start);
}

// Add margin for all sides
// @param {string} $top
// @param {string} $end
// @param {string} $bottom
// @param {string} $start
// ----------------------------------------------------------
@mixin margin($top, $end: $top, $bottom: $top, $start: $end) {
  @include property(margin, $top, $end, $bottom, $start);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your mixin code too? And why can't you combine both padding and margin to one mixin and chose the appropriate one by passing the correct arguments ?

Comment: It appears as though you are using a preprocessor; please [edit] your question and include the tag for that preprocessor.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I am using standard sass preprocessed with gulp. I added a gulp task in the answers that does what I needed in a limited way

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a specific fix for `dir`, as it is my main problem, not other duplications which are a tiny proportion of my bundle.

Pretty simple, and does the job, 0 seconds. It does not merge up or down, but instead removes the code and adds a chunk with the merged directional code at the end. (it doesn't matter for directional, as everything maintains its order and specificity)

```
function joinDirections(contents) {
  // This includes multi directional selectors, like `[dir="ltr"] sel, [dir="rtl"] sel`,
  // Which go into the ltr pile, but it is ok as the rest (`sel, [dir="rtl"] sel`) is still good.
  const dirExp = /\[dir="(.*?)"\](.*?){\s*([^}]*?)\s*}/gm;

  let directions = {};

  let matches;
  while (matches = dirExp.exec(contents)) {
    if (!(matches[1] in directions))
      directions[matches[1]] = {};
    if (!(matches[2] in directions[matches[1]]))
      directions[matches[1]][matches[2]] = '';
    directions[matches[1]][matches[2]] += matches[3];
  }

  contents = contents.replace(dirExp, '');
  let directionalContents = '';

  Object.keys(directions).forEach(dir => {
    Object.keys(directions[dir]).forEach(selector => {
      directionalContents += `[dir="${dir}"]${selector}{${directions[dir][selector]}}\n`;
    });
  });

  return contents + directionalContents;
}
```